# How to apply multiple filter in Data Frame?

Tags: pandas, feature-selection, data-cleaning, data-science-model, text-filter

**How to implement multiple filters for checking data cell in a range ?**

Suppose, I have a list of numbers like,

---

```
range_1 = [ 70 ,15,5,7,3,7,8,3,2, 63  ]

# and

range_1 = [ 50, 56, 80, 61, 83, 87, 13, 58, 43, 24, 84, 54, 64,36, 48  ]
```

And I want to check any column values exist within these two lists.

---

Any **suggestion would be appreciated**

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
data.loc[ data['age'].isin(range_1) & data['height'].isin(range_2) ]
```

Comment: Yes, Excellent @10xAI,  It's work, I just forgot about  `isin()` method.